# Люмпен, маргинал, филистер и мещанин

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова

Не могу уловить тонкие отличия между следующими словами.

**люмпен**

> Деклассированный слой людей (преступники, бродяги, нищие), а также
>   человек, принадлежащий к такому слою.

**маргинал**

> 1. Тот, кто утратил прежние социальные связи, находится на периферии своей социальной среды, не приспособился к новым условиям жизни и не
>      имеет устойчивого социального статуса; изгой.
> 2. Тот, кто находится на грани общества (бомжи, бездомные, безработные и т.п.) .

**филистер**

> Человек с узким, ограниченным умственным кругозором и ханжеским
>   поведением; обыватель, мещанин.

**мещанин**

> Человек с мелкими, сугубо личными интересами, с узким кругозором и
>   неразвитыми вкусами, безразличный к интересам общества.

Если разница между (люмпеном,маргиналом) и (филистером,мещанином) прослеживается из определений, то разница между люмпеном и маргиналом и между филистером и мещанином - не совсем очевидна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Люмпен is somewhat close to пролетарий with negative connotation. 
It is sorta of "bad" пролетарий or even "деклассированный элемент".

Маргинал is wider. For example, панк can be considered маргинал, but not always he is a lumpen, any member of left/right extremist organization is a маргинал. Occupy movement can be called маргинальный, but is hardly люмпенский, since many of activists belong no intellectual elite (students, professors, artists etc.)

Филистер/мещанин pair is quite alike in sense of this "marxist/non-marxist" differentiation. Мещанин in its first, historical sense is a representative of specific social class actually. Somewhat close to буржуа, but having much lower social status.

In it second sense, which is the main one nowadays, мещанин indeed means someone who just don't care about any kind of spiritual and social values, deeply selfish and narrow minded person.

The same about filister (which comes from филистимлянин in german). It believed that this word had been used by new time german students do describe...an average burger (a close relative of russian мещанин) who despises any kind of "abstract" intellectual activity, whether it would be, say, a literature, or archeology or whatever else you should study in the university.

This is very close to мещанин indeed. It's just that in russian it tends to be slightly less social marked. Besides, it's is definitely more "bookish" term compared to мещанин :)

Comment: В 1785 году в одной из схваток [студентов и горожан] был убит студент. При погребении пастор университетской церкви произнес проповедь за основу которой взял смерть царя Саула в бою против филистимлян. Пастор имел в виду внушить молодежи, что убитый студент погиб в результате собственной буйной жизни и дурной нравственности, подобно тому, как Саул пал потому, что не угодил Иегове. Этот случай как бы узаконил переносный смысл слова филистимляне. Впрочем, установление переносного значения ограниченный мещанин было поддержано созвучием слова Philister (филистимлянин) с намеком пфистер (булочник).

Comment: Это цитата из книги Бориса Казанского ["Приключения слов"](http://fb2.booksgid.com/content/34/boris-kazanskiy-priklyucheniya-slov/21.html).

Comment: _Люмпен_ is not a “somewhat close to _пролетарий_ with negative connotation”. _Люмпен_ **is** a kind of _пролетарий_ (i. e. employee, it even may be actually called _люмпен-пролетарий_), but very poor one, making do with casual (irregular) earnings at any menial job.

Comment: I’ve been about original meaning of term _люмпен_, since you seems to had been too. Now it also might be used to call any impoverished person, then the word have no connection to _пролетариат_ at all.